# Write a file with different name

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I need to perform the following two tasks in a .txt file which contains more than 500 lines with lots of information: dates, hours, comments, names, etc.

(1) Replace the substrings "p. m." and "a. m." to "PM" and "AM". (Already did)
(2) I need to save the output into another file since I need to keep the original one. (This is the main issue).

I'm familiar with the concepts of open, read and close. But I have not solved this task yet:

```
with open('Dates of arrival.txt','r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    filedata = file.read()
    filedata.replace("p.\xa0m.", "PM").replace("a.\xa0m.", "AM")  # This output is the one I want to save as a .txt file.
```

I know I have to open another file to contain the information, but the file 'dates of arrival1.txt' is empty.

```
with open('dates of arrival1.txt', 'w') as wf:
    wf.write(file)  # I am not sure if file is the correct word to put there.
```

So, the main problem is how to nest these two codes into one in order to perform the tasks (1) and (2) and save the output into a .txt file. It may not be as difficult as I think but I need a little help on this one.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: _So, the main problem is how to nest these two codes into one._ Can you be more specific about what the issue is?

Comment: `replace()` is a non-destructive method. It does not replace data in place but returns a copy with replacements.

Comment: In regards to comment (1): I explained a bit more. (2) Yes, I know, I just want to save the output in a .txt file.

Comment: @AlejandroNieves _I need to save the output into another file since I need to keep the original one. (This is the main issue)._ I’m still not sure I understand. You wrote that you’re not sure if _file is the correct word to put there_, where does `file` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're happy with your string  replace statements

Code can be simplified to the following:

```
with open('Dates of arrival.txt','r', encoding='utf-8') as file, open('dates of arrival1.txt', 'w') as wf:
    wf.write(file.read().replace("p.\xa0m.", "PM").replace("a.\xa0m.", "AM"))
```

Comment: Great! This is just what I needed. Thank you!